# How do I create a custom shapes in the shape of a circle in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, shapes

I'm designing my own shapes, but I can't get them to align or replicate the way I want them to. I need them to be in a perfect circle as shown below. How would I do this?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Start by creating your ring and a single divider:

[image]

Duplicate and rotate your dividing shape as many times as you need around the cirlce. I've used a transform effect because it's easy to enter the correct number of copies and rotation angle but you could just as easily do it manually:

[image]

Expand everything and create two compound paths, one for your ring and one from the dividers (just select them and hit <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>8</kbd>). Make sure your dividers are on top, select both compound paths and hit the "Minus Front" Pathfinder button:

[image]

Your finished shapes:

[image]

Color and style as you wish. For the text create a new circle and use the Type on a Path Tool:

[image]